# Applescript Auto Open Downloaded File

Tags: applescript

How should an Apple Script look like to automatically open a file named testfile downloaded to the Downloads folder and run with a program testprogram?

I feel it should be a pretty simple template, and I am having trouble finding much to accomplish it.

Comment: What? You want an AppleScript Script which opens up a specific file, after it is downloaded, with an specific appliction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a folder action like this with Automator:

[image]

Finder's `open` command also has a `using` specifier for specifying the application:

```
tell application "Finder"
    open POSIX file "/usr/share/doc/bash/bash.html" using (path to application "Safari")
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

This example uses Microsoft Word to open testFile.rtf.  Update the code with your info and attach the folder action to your target folder.

```
on adding folder items to theFolder after receiving theFiles

    set appPath to quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to applications folder) & "Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Word.app")

    repeat with aFile in theFiles
        tell application "Finder" to aFile's name = "testfile.rtf"
        if the result then
            set filePath to quoted form of aFile's POSIX path
            do shell script "open -a " & appPath & space & filePath
        end if
    end repeat
end adding folder items to
```

If you manually want to open the file, try this:

```
set appPath to quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to applications folder) & "Microsoft Office 2011/Microsoft Word.app")
set filePath to quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to documents folder) & "testFile.rtf")
try
    do shell script "open -a " & appPath & space & filePath
end try
```